# How to show an specific crop of an image in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im having an very basic problem that is driving me crazy with a Use Case im trying to implement.

I have a big image that I want to divide in a 100x100 exact squares.

If a user click on a place in this big image it needs to render a new view with the exact square where clicks. So, for instance, if he clicks on the position 40,50 of the big image, I will open a new view, with a square of x:40, y:50, h:100, w:100.

I was trying to use ImagePicker for that. This is my code:

```
 import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import ImageEditor from '@react-native-community/image-editor';

const initialImage = { uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png' };

export default class CroppedImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { image: initialImage };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.cropImage();
  }

  async cropImage() {
    // Construct a crop data object.
    const cropData = {
      offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      size: { width: 20, height: 20 }
      //  displaySize:{width:20, height:20}, THESE 2 ARE OPTIONAL.
      //  resizeMode:'contain',
    };
    // Crop the image.
    try {
      await ImageEditor.cropImage(
        initialImage.uri,
        cropData,
        successURI => {
          console.log('oi');
        },
        error => {
          console.log('cropImage,', error);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error caught in this.cropImage:', error);
    }
  }
  render() {
    const resizeMode = 'center';
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={this.state.image}
          style={styles.image}
        ></ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Im getting this error here:

```
Error caught in this.cropImage: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'cropImage' of undefined]
```

Any lights on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.
[Exapmle](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-editor/blob/master/example/src/App.js)

```js
async cropImage(){
  const cropData = {
    offset: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    size: {
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    }
    //  displaySize:{width:20, height:20}, THESE 2 ARE OPTIONAL.
    //  resizeMode:'contain',
  };

  try {
    const croppedImageURI = await ImageEditor.cropImage(
      initialImage.uri,
      cropData,
    );

    if (croppedImageURI) {
      this.setState({
        image: croppedImageURI
      });
    }
  } catch (cropError) {
    //this.setState({cropError});
  }
}
```